# Study for Ternary and N-ary relations: books and practice material recommendations?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, reference-request, book-recommendation

I have learnt the topic binary relations and its types and i am curious about ternary and N-ary relations and i want to learn about there properties.

So please can I be recommended books and online practice materials, notes or lectures on the very topic ?

Thank you.

Comment: The topic of "relations" is very, very, very broad. It's like asking for recommendation on the study of "functions" or "numbers". You would need to be much more specific to get good recommendations.

Comment: Maybe you are interested in [hypergraphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph)?

Comment: @Mees de Vries: To be specific, for the properties of ternary and N-ary relations.

Comment: Maybe this will help make my point: you say you studied binary relations. What do you mean by that? Did you study equivalence relations? Functions (which are a special case of relations)? Did you study order relations? Partial orders, linear orders, well-orders -- do you know about ordinals? Confluent relations? Did you study graph theory? Set theory? These are just some examples of very deep subjects that can fall under "binary relations". Similarly, relations of higher arity are present in lots of fields of mathematics, but it (usually) makes fairly little sense to study them in isolation.